# K-means clustering on text data?

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, data-mining, k-means

For simpler understanding I am explaining with smaller example. 
I have 2 sets : 

I have 10 unique string ids. id1,id2,id3,id4,id5... id10 

I have 3 unique c-ids: cid1,cid2,cid3

There is a mapping between 2 sets but not within the values of same sets. 

The mapping is say : 

id1 : cid1,cid2

id2 : cid3

id3 : cid1
... so on..

I need to cluster set of ids(strings) against cids(strings) and vice a versa.

Right now I have created a csv file like below.  (similar to sparse)

id1 , cid1

id1 , cid2

id3 , cid3

.

.

I run the k-means in Weka but not sure if this is the right way. All those ids are actually features / attributes which do not have any specific order. But the way I am representing , the columns are treated as attribute values. How can I convert it into features?

Comment: has it got to be in weka? (are you be willing to try some other tool?)

Comment: I am willing to try any other tool. Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For kmeans you have to create `equal length` vectors. One possible way is - given there are three unique Ids `cid1`, `cid2` and `cid3` so you create a vector of length `3` each taking a binary value (`0` or `1`) denoting the `absence` or `presence` of that unique id.

```
id => [cid1, cid2, cid3]
```

i.e. above examples can be written as:

```
id1,1,1,0
id2,0,0,1
id3,1,0,1
...
```

Then I think you can cluster using kmeans. I do not know the semantics of Ids here so can't really comment on how well will it cluster.

Comment: Does that mean , represent the features in the form of dense matrix? In above example it will be 10X3 matrix with values 1 if there is mapping and 0 otherwise right? If this is correct how can I do it in Weka?

Comment: Not much idea on Weka.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are willing to try any other tool that will do the clustering, I recommend taking a look at [SPMF](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/).

> SPMF is an open-source data mining mining library written in Java,
>   specialized in pattern mining.
>
> It is distributed under the GPL v3 license.
>
> It offers implementations of 89 data mining algorithms for:
>
> **sequential pattern mining, association rule mining, itemset mining,
>   sequential rule mining, clustering. The source code of each algorithm
>   can be integrated in other Java software.**
>
> Moreover, SPMF can be used as a standalone program with a simple user
>   interface or from the command line.

You can download the GUI program or the source code from [here](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/index.php?link=download.php)

Documentation and data-set description can be found on [this page](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/index.php?link=documentation.php).

---

For KMeans the program accepts only **integer values** *(there is a workaround for strings)* **separated by single spaces** and also it assumes that **all rows have the same length.**

```
1 2 3 4
1 6 8 8
1 2 3 3
2 4 5 5
4 7 8 7
7 6 8 9
4 4 3 3
2 2 5 5
7 5 5 5
5 6 8 9
```

The output file format is defined as follows. **Each line is a cluster** and lists the vectors contained in the cluster. A vector is a list of double values separated by "," and between the "[" and "]" characters.

```
cluster 1: [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0][1.0,2.0,3.0,3.0][2.0,4.0,5.0,5.0][4.0,4.0,3.0,3.0][2.0,2.0,5.0,5.0]
cluster 2: [7.0,6.0,8.0,9.0][1.0,6.0,8.0,8.0][4.0,7.0,8.0,7.0][5.0,6.0,8.0,9.0]
cluster 3: [7.0,5.0,5.0,5.0]
```

***However if your data-set has only a few distinct strings a "find and replace" will do the job.***

In any other case you can use [R](http://www.r-project.org/)